# FBSDKLoginButton Logout state greyed out

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I was trying to implement the new FDSDKLoginButton and after I login the button text changes to 'Log out'. But the button its now a very light blue instead of the usual deep facebook blue. Is this normal?

[image]